# Duplicating Image within Drag and Drop Grid

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drag and drop where you drag images from the sidebar into a grid. It clones the image when it goes into the grid. Although, when I drag an image in the grid to another grid space, it copies it, and I don't want it to. This is my code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var el = ev.target;
    if (!el.classList.contains('dropzone')) {
       el = ev.target.parentNode;
       ev.target.remove();
    }
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div5, #div6, #div7, #div8{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div9, #div10, #div11, #div12{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div13, #div14, #div15, #div16{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row2 {
 clear: both;
}

.row3 {
 clear: both;
}

.row4 {
 clear: both;
}

body {
  transition: margin .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
.row {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
  padding-top: 15px;
  }

  .sidenav a {
  font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var el = ev.target;
    if (!el.classList.contains('dropzone')) {
       el = ev.target.parentNode;
       ev.target.remove();
    }
    el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.marginLeft= "0";
}

</script>
<body>

 <div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Materials</span>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div2" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div3" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div4" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div class="row2">

<div id="div5" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div6" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div7" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div8" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

<div class="row3">

<div id="div9" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div10" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div11" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div12" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

<div class="row4">

<div id="div13" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div14" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div15" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div16" class="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

<a href="#">

    <img src="bricks.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">

   Bricks

</a>

<a href="#">

    <img src="halfbrick.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1.3" width="55" height="55">

   Half Brick

</a>

<a href="#">

    <img src="halfbrick2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1.6" width="55" height="55">

   Half Brick

</a>

<a href="#">

    <img src="#" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="55" height="55">

  Stone

</a>
<a href="#">

    <img src="#" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="55" height="55">

    Wood

  </a>
  <a href="#">

    <img src="#" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4" width="55" height="55">

  Eraser

  </a>
</div>

</body>
<style>

#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div5, #div6, #div7, #div8{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div9, #div10, #div11, #div12{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div13, #div14, #div15, #div16{
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row2 {
 clear: both;
}

.row3 {
 clear: both;
}

.row4 {
 clear: both;
}

body {
  transition: margin .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
.row {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
  padding-top: 15px;
  }

  .sidenav a {
  font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that ev.target refers to the div where item is being dropped, so contains('dropzone') always returns true.

[this](https://jsfiddle.net/vignz_pie/7j86tyq0/1/) worked for me:

```
function drag(ev, source) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("parent", source.parentNode.tagName);

}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var parent= ev.dataTransfer.getData("parent");
    // console.log(parent);
    if(parent == "A"){
      el.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    }
    else{
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
}
```

Here you can store parentNode.tagName(either 'a' or 'div') of the dragged item into dataTransfer and access it in the drop() function, based on which you clone the item or simple move it.

Comment: Thank You so much! Sorry for taking so long to respond.